# Problem finding limit - which function is asymptotically larger

Tags: limits, asymptotics, exponentiation, factorial

I have a homework question, so please don't answer fully but I would appreciate a push in the right direction.

Basically we need to figure out if $n^{n+\frac{1}{2}}e^{-n}$ is larger,smaller, or equal to $n!$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

I checked the answer, and it turns out they are equal. when $n$ goes to infinity, one divided by the other does not yield $0$. But how do I show it?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Laplace method?

Comment: No. I've never heard or was taught the Laplace method.

Comment: And you haven't been shown Stirling's formula either?

Comment: this may be useful: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation

Comment: We have. Is stirling approximation the way to solve this?

Comment: Take a look at Stirling's formula.  Notice the $n^{n+1/2} e^{-n}$?

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to take logs of both sides, and for $n!$ consider the integral of $\log x.$

Comment: Thanks for the great advice. But as said in the comments, I did manage to solve it using stirling approximation. Will accept answer to close this page. Thank you.

Comment: @OriaGruber Doing it this way is not better, but slightly simpler than Stirling (you are actually proving a form of Stirling approx.)